NumPy array values in Enum
I am looking for a way to declare immutable numpy arrays for a module. My current attempt involves utilising the Enum class. However, if I attempt to assign numpy arrays as values to Enum class attributes, Python attempts to broadcast the different values together and throws an error.
Here's a minimum (not-)working example:
import enum
import numpy as np

class Foo(enum.Enum):
    BAR = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    BAZ = np.array([4, 5])

This raises an error:
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)

I've noticed that using lists instead of np.arrays works fine. Similarly, I can wrap the np.array into a tuple, however I'm uneasy about this solution as it feels somewhat "patchy". Is there a way to use numpy arrays as Enum values? Or perhaps there is a better way of declaring static numpy arrays in a module?

I get no error from your example, running in Python 3.10.12. Is that the only code needed to trigger the error for you?

I can replicate the error with just the code provided on python 3.10.12 on mac

@NickODell Yes, this is the only code needed to trigger the error. I was testing this earlier in a Jupyter notebook, but I get the same error when running this in Python 3.11.8 terminal on a mac

Your code runs on 1.24 numpy.  But the whole idea itself is 'patchy'.  It does not make immutable arrays.  Foo.BAR.value can be changed with any in-place numpy operation.  I get your error if I try to do some sort of math with Foo.BAR.value and Foo.BAZ.value, just as if I worked with the 2 arrays without this class.

Does this answer your question? In short, just create your array, say a, then use a.flags.writeable = False or a.setflags(write=False). Just to be clear: your primary goal is creating immutable arrays rather than an Enum of arrays, is that correct?

An Enum value is supposed to be comparable which each other. I guess this is why the simple existence of this Enum cause such a comparison (at creation), and then the error. Any anyway, all that says is that you couldn't Enum.FOO=somethingelese. It doesn't make it unmutable. Just the enum field cannot be changed.

To me the question asking for "immutable arrays" can be understood in two ways (on two levels, so to speak):

Do you want to ensure that for a certain attribute, a new value cannot be reassigned once an initial value has been assigned; for example, once an array has been assigned to BAR, no new array can be assigned there?
In this case, use some immutable Python data structure to hold your Numpy array, such as a tuple, a named tuple (which can be defined in two ways, see here and here), or a frozen dataclass. This will not ensure that values inside the array cannot be altered, however.

Do you want to ensure that values inside an array cannot be altered?
In this case, set the WRITEABLE flag on your array to False.


Both possibilities can be combined as follows, for example (here, I am using a frozen dataclass to prevent attribute reassignment and setflags() to set the array's WRITEABLE flag):
from dataclasses import dataclass, FrozenInstanceError
import numpy as np

@dataclass(frozen=True)  # `frozen=True`: disable reassigning to `Foo`'s fields
class Foo:
    BAR: np.ndarray
    BAZ: np.ndarray
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.BAR.setflags(write=False)  # `write=False`: disable reassigning to
        self.BAZ.setflags(write=False)  #     the entries of the arrays
        
foo = Foo(BAR=np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), BAZ=np.asarray([4, 5]))

try:
    foo.BAR = 42  # Try to assign a new value to `foo.BAR`
except FrozenInstanceError as error:
    print(error)  # >>> cannot assign to field 'BAR'
try:
    foo.BAR[0] = 42  # Try to assign a new value to an entry of `foo.BAR`
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)  # >>> assignment destination is read-only

As a final note, keep in mind what the documentation of frozen dataclasses says:

It is not possible to create truly immutable Python objects.

Thus, there will always be a way to circumvent your immutability measures in Python, if one really tries to do so.
